# Google Assistant implementation without Google play console

Tags: android, voice-recognition, google-play-console, google-assistant-sdk

I'm implementing an **Enterprise product** and they are providing their app through their Website, not from **Google Play Console**.

I just wanted to **integrate Google Assistant** into that application. But docs says, we should *publish* the app into *Play console*. then only **Voice input** from Google Assistant will work like that. So I need to do that **without publishing** the app into Google Play Console. Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that without publishing your app on the play store. During development also, you have to deploy your app on an internal test track in the play console.

Your app actions will be reviewed and then only they are available to your users.

From the docs

> Your App Actions won't be available to your users until they've been reviewed and approved.

https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/get-started#request-review

Comment: Thank you so much dude. Do we have any other options to control the application over voice action? Kindly suggest something

Comment: You can call your API through google action and pass the data that you can update in your database. If the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so it can help others with similar issues.